# Adding a Geopackage layer as a hardwired input to an algorithm in the QGIS graphical modeler

Tags: qgis, qgis-modeler, geopackage

Update- August 2020-  you can now load vector geopackage layers directly in 3.14 https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/issues/30827

I have a geopackage layer that I want to always be used in an algorithm in the QGIS 3.6 graphical modeler. When I use the triple dots to navigate to the geopackage it doesn't give me the option to choose a layer in the geopackage. Is there syntax I can use in the file path to identify the layer? In the example screenshot I want to use the layer AOI_Poly2 from the geopackage AOI as the mask layer. It seems like it will work but it chooses the first polygon layer in the gpkg (AOI_poly). I have tried appending  "|layername=AOI_poly2" to the file path but the dialog won't let me save. I am using windows 10. [image]

Comment: I don't understand when the windows file explorer is coming. Can you edit your question? You mean you need to add the layer name to the path geopackage path?

Comment: Yes- I hope the question is clearer now.

Comment: Yes, better indeed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I tried to create a string input, with the default value `/home/etienne/test.gpkg|layername=layer4`, I can use this input as `Input layer`, but yes I can't select it for `Mask layer`. This looks like a bug to me.

What I could do is to use the `string concatenation algorithm`. Use a string input with the geopackage path and append the name of the layer you would like to use. I don't know why, but the model will allow to use the output of the algorithm. It is a workaround. Maybe you can report this bug to QGIS on github?

[image]

Comment: Thanks that is a valid work around. - I’ll add this to the Qgis bug report. Really l think it is that this is just one of the places that geopackage hasn’t been fully implemented yet.

Comment: Added this as a feature request: https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/issues/30827